# Short story about a huge blanket blocking the sun, thereby freezing earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What I can remember about story. A man invents a material that can be made in space; It blocks 100% of the suns energy (details as to why can not remember). He decides to create a massive blanket that will in effect create a permanent solar eclipse.

*At this point I am unsure if I am adding to it or if it was part of the story:*
I think a hero then goes out to the blanket, gets rid of it and does away with the villain.

I can not remember who wrote it, but believe it was part of a scifi anthology as I remember reading other short stories at the same time period in my life (some 30-40 years ago).

What is the title of this work and who wrote it?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't Mr. Burns?

Comment: I don't know the name, but I remember that the mad scientist also built a super underground bunker for a select group for 'breeding' after the freeze.

Comment: @GunnerMiller: Dr. Strangelove!

Comment: @Paul not Dr.Strangelove he used a bomb as for Gunner. that does tweak a memory in me in relation to that story.

Answer (score 4):

Plotwise this sounds very like *Sunstrike* by George Carpozi which is a novel but not a short story. That said it's not very lengthy. You can check it on [amazon here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0523403658)

It has to be said the negative customer reviews are quite amusing!

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you add a brief description of your proposal?  It'll just help the OP and any future viewers determine if this is what they are looking for.  Thanks!